# zendframework routing based on the GET parameter

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have a page in my website (zendframework 1) that parses the GET parameter and query its data from the database to show it to the user.

```
-> my current url : https://example.com/index.php/product/info?id=123
```

i want my url to be more human readable

```
-> https://example.com/index.php/product/iphone-7s-white
```

so basicaly i want to parse the GET parameter in the url and query the name of the product from the database in order to make it appear as the page name in the url.

i came across some solutions, one of them is achieved by looping through the database (in bootstrap.php) and adding a route for each product, but this seems like a mess, (products can reach 200k or maybe more than that).

is there a better solution for my problem ? thanks in advance

Comment: You could have a slug in your product table and then try to get the line with the slug corresponding to the route parameter. Have you tried that and if not where are you stuck?

Comment: i just cant figure out how to do the bootstrap thing based on the get params.
the slug is basically the product name + the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, ZF1 provides a default route that leads to the controller/action of the names from the url.

You can add custom routes from the `application/Bootstrap.php` file by adding a function there:

```
/**
 * This method loads URL routes defined in /application/configs/routes.ini
 * @return Zend_Router 
 */
protected function _initRouter() {
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute(
        'user',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('product/:slug', array(
            'controller' => 'product',
            'action'     => 'details',
        ), array(
            'slug' => '[A-Za-z0-9-]+',
        ))
    );
    return $router;
}
```

And here you go!

---

As described by Chris, you need to change your controller code to handle the request. Another solution would be to use an extra action.

```
final class ProductController
{
    public function infoAction()
    {
        $product = $table->find($this->_param('id'));
        $this->view->product = $product;
    }

    public function detailsAction()
    {
        $product = $table->fetch(['slug' => $this->_param('slug')]);
        $this->view->product = $product;
        $this->render('info');
    }
}
```

Now, assuming you do a lot of processing in `infoAction`, you could go with a forward:

```
final class ProductController
{
    public function infoAction()
    {
        $product = $table->find($this->_param('id'));
        $this->view->product = $product;
    }

    public function detailsAction()
    {
        $product = $table->fetch(['slug' => $this->_param('slug')]);
        $this->forward('info', 'product', [
            'id' => $product->id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

It is less efficient (2 requests instead of one), but allows you to reuse your code.

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer, could you further elaborate the code you posted. i dont fully understand the slug part, how is it supposed to replace the id in the original url?

Comment: The idea is that you have to store a slug in your DB, the slug is the title of your article and has to be a PK (or unique) so you can query against it. Then this route will trigger that controller and pass a slug parameter for you, then you have to query your DB where slug => $slug, and if not found you trigger a 404 error, else you display the product.

Comment: Edited as per your comment Chris. I would argue the slug does not need to be a primary key, but needs to be unique and an index to have an efficient search.